# Spooling in Oracle adds spaces to columns... how can I avoid it?

Tags: oracle, spool

I'm saving the results of a query in a csv file but unwanted spaces are added to some of the fields, when the original data in the database does not contain them.

For example, if one of the rows in the DB has the values "how", "are" and "you", what I get in the file after spooling is a line like :

> ```
> "how    |  are |you      "
> ```

(the editor doesn't let me write more spaces, but you can imagine there are plenty of them)

When I just want it to be :

> ```
> "how|are|you"
> ```

I've tried several setting options with no result. Is there a way to avoid these spaces? Thanks in advance!

What I got so far:

```
SET ECHO OFF;
SET NEWP 0 SPACE 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS OFF TRIM OFF TAB OFF;
set colsep '|';
set lines 130;

spool myfile.csv

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE;

spool off;
```

This goes inside a call to sqlplus.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Added to the main post ;)

Comment: What is the end goal of getting this into a CSV format?  E.g., do you just want to be able to view it cleanly in Excel?  Or is it for subsequent automated data processing?

Comment: It's the second case, the data needs further processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're trying something like this:

```
set colsep "|"

with demo as
   ( select 'Various' as col1, 'test' as col2, 'examples' as col3 from dual
     union all select 'How', 'are', 'you' from dual )
select col1, col2, col3
from   demo;

COL1   |COL2|COL3
-------|----|--------
Various|test|examples
How    |are |you
```

Unfortunately SQL*Plus isn't designed for unloading data like this - the separator is strictly for columns. You'll have to concatenate the values with pipes yourself e.g.

```
col1 || '|' || col2 || '|' || col3
```

(and watch out for column formatting e.g. dates).

Comment: good observation, I'm probably wrong guessing on leading and trailing blanks in the column data.

Comment: In what way could there be problems with the column formatting? One of the fields is actually a date, but I can't imagine any risk.

Comment: I just mean the format for dates will depend on `nls_date_format` and your desktop territory settings unless you explicitly set a format with `to_char`. Also make sure `linesize` is set big enough for the output record.

Answer (score 2):

Your table contains columns defined as `CHAR(nn)` which *fills the values with blanks* to the full length or your application stored the additional blanks along the strings.

use `rtrim` to remove trailing blanks - instaed of

```
 select c1||'|'||c2||'|'||c3
 from tst;
```

use

```
 select rtrim(c1)||'|'||rtrim(c2)||'|'||rtrim(c3)
 from tst;
```

use `ltrim` as well if you have both leading and trailing blanks

```
 select ltrim(rtrim(c1))||'|'||ltrim(rtrim(c2))||'|'||ltrim(rtrim(c3))
 from tst;
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in comment the function `trim` can be used instead

```
 select  trim(c1)||'|'||trim(c2)||'|'||trim(c3)
 from tst;
```

Comment: Instead of ltrim(rtrim(c1)) you could just use trim(c1)

Comment: Well, with the trim() function and setting the separator inside the select clause (instead of using colsep), I'm getting pretty much what I wanted. I'll run some more tests but for now it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on Linux or Unix, consider:

```
sqlplus ***/***@*** << EOF | sed -e 's/[\t ]*[,$]/,/g' > outputfile.txt
set head off
set colsep ','
etc...
select whatever from sometable;
exit;
EOF
```